# detect radio/checkbox 'checked' states in jquery UI. Underlying buttons don't update

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-button

I'm using the jQuery UI [button widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/button/#radio) in a form that I need to validate for some radio/check box elements.

*According to the demo in the provided link -*

> Their (the original elements)
>   associated label is styled to appear
>   as the button, while the underlying
>   input is updated on click.

if you inspect even the example page I provided the underlying button elements do not get updated with *anything*.  `Note` - the middle radio button in the example is checked by default.

I am using the following code to detect button states - oddly enough its always true (figured it'd be false).

```
$el = $("#someCheckbox");
if($el.attr('checked')){ //do stuff }
```

It looks like I can get the button state from the label jquery ui uses as the button style `(a la class="ui-state-active)`, but I would like to avoid reading labels and stick to validating the actual radio buttons.

---

Am I pulling the form data wrong by accessing the original radio button?

### OR

Is this potentially a bug in the jquery ui butotn widget?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just checked the demo pages at jqueryui.com. Looks like it works just ok there. However let jQuery decide if the input is checked. Try

```
$el = $("#someCheckbox");
if( $el.is(':checked') ){ //do stuff }
```

Hope that helps.